# How to display a new table when clicking on a link in an existing table?

Tags: jsf

I am rather new to JSF and I'd like to implement the following feature:

I have a table "Employer" with one of the fields containing a button

*EMPLOYER*

| 1 | (some employer info)  | **[button]** |
| 2 | (other employer info) | **[button]** |

When I click on one of the buttons above, I need a call to the backend (normally Ajax) to display a new table "Worker" with the information corresponding to the row of the button, **below** the first table.

*EMPLOYER*

...

*WORKER*

| 1 | (some worker info)  |
| 2 | (other worker info) |

There is a one-2-many relationship between Employer and Worker.
I do not want to use *<p:rowToggler>*

Could you please advise of the best way to proceed? Thanks.

Currently, the structure looks like:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myAction.employers}" var="emp" rowIndexVar="index" id="employerTable">
   ...
   <p:column>
     <f:facet .../>
     TODO
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dataTable id="workerTable">
   ...
</p:dataTable>
```